# Windows Phone App Policies

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to publish an app for Windows Phone 8.1 and 10 (Only Mobile),

I already published a lot of apps on the same account. This is the same of another already on the store with just a different icon (different customer, it's B to B) and name, but **from the 16 of october** *the policy for the windows store changed* and now my app is blocked with the following reason:

> App Policies: 10.1 Inaccurate Representation
>
> Your app and its associated metadata must accurately and clearly
>   reflect the source, functionality, and features of your app.
>
> •All aspects of your app should accurately describe the functions,
>   features and any important limitations of your app, including required
>   or supported input devices. Your app may not use a name or icon
>   similar to that of other apps, and may not claim to be from a company,
>   government body, or other entity if you do not have permission to make
>   that representation.
>
> •Your app must be fully functional and must provide appropriate
>   functionality for each targeted device family.
>
> •Keywords may not exceed seven unique terms and should be relevant to
>   your app.
>
> •Your app must have distinct and informative metadata and must provide
>   a valuable and quality user experience.
>
> Locations: Metadata
>
> Notes To Developer
>
> The app's "pin to start", "app list", or "games hub" icon does not
>   accurately represent the app and/or is a default icon. The
>   "pin-to-start" tile submitted in the submission package, which is
>   different from the icon and tile images in the app metadata, must
>   uniquely represent the app so users can associate it with your app.
>   For information about icons and tiles in Windows apps, see
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948(v=vs.105).aspx.

I searched on the internet but I didn't find anything useful for this problem and I don't get what are those "pin to start", "app list", and"games hub" they are talking about in the Note to Developers.

Anyone knows the solution?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it seems that you haven’t set the title images for your app. So I would like to suggest you to delete all of icons in your project and  open **Package.appxmanifest** in Visual Studio and select the **Visual Assets**. Please make sure to replace all default titles with the correct size image that represents your app. And then you could need to create your app package and resubmit your app again.

By the way, if your project is UWP, you could use [UWP Title Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shenchauhan.UWPTileGenerator) tool to generate correct size title quickly.

**Update:**

As your project is Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, firstly, please prepare the correct size title, and then **right-click Assets--choose Add--Existing item**, you can choose the correct size title to replace the default title.
[image]

Then **right-click Package.appxmanifest, choose open with--XML(Text)Editor**, then you could need to make sure that the path of title is correct.

[image]
 Finally, you may need to **rebuild the project** in order for the tile titles to show up properly.

Hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for replying! My app is not UWP, only for windows phone silverlight 8.1 but it's also compatible with windows phone 10. both with and without windows phone 10 compatibility in the store we got this error. and I can't see the Visual asset section in the appxmanifest, is it only for 10?

Comment: First thanks for your help, second I have just a question: the sizes in the name (71<71, 150x150, 41x41,...) are meaning the px sizes of the images? because unfortunatly my appxmanifest looks exactly like your. the only doubt is about the sizes that might be incorrect

Comment: Yes,the size in the name (71 x 71, 150 x 150, 41 x 41) are meaning the px sizes of the images.

Comment: I'm trying the submission now, I will let you know, thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but they wasted some time for the analisys. This didn't work, they still rejected the app with the same reason. Any other idea?

Comment: If you still experience the same issue, please contact [Dev Center Support](http://aka.ms/storesupport) so that you will be assisted better.